# how to make android app with listview using data from realm?

Tags: android, listview, realm

I need some help for my homework here..
My app is using google map api v2 and storing location and some comment into realm.I want to make listview with using data from realm.

**LocationData.java**

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class LocationData extends RealmObject {
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String title;
    private String detailInfo;

    public String getUriString() {
        return uriString;
    }

    private String uriString;

    public String getDetailInfo() {
        return detailInfo;
    }

    public void setDetailInfo(String detailInfo) {
        this.detailInfo = detailInfo;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setUriString(String uriString){ this.uriString = uriString; }


}
```

**ListViewActivity.java**   *   this is just copied from sample code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        ArrayList<String> labelList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=1; i<=20; i++){
            labelList.add("List Item "+i);
        }


        CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, 0, labelList);

        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        list.setDivider(null);
    }

}
```

**CustomAdapter.java** *this is also copied sample code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ArrayList<String> labelList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=1; i<=20; i++){
            labelList.add("List Item "+i);
        }

        CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, 0, labelList);

        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        list.setDivider(null);
    }

}
```

I want to know how can I load from data from realm and set the data for listview.

Comment: Please post your `CustomAdapter` source code here.

Answer (score 0):

You posted the code for ListViewActvity.java twice instead of posting CustomeAdapter.java so I'm going to GUESS that it's extending the ListAdapter object....

I'll give you a short version of what you need to do and some sample code from a very simple array adapter.

1. create a layout file that defines how to display the information from 1 object in your list.
2. In your CustomAdapter's contructor, you would typically save the context, and a pointer to the list of objects.  In my example I also save a reference to the inflator, but you can instead look it up every time you need it.
3. In CustomAdapter, override the getView() method.  This method is called for each member object that the listview needs to display.  It will have the job of inflating the layout from #1 and assigning values to various views within the layout.  **It's up to you how to display each item**.  getView will return the inflated view.
4. In your main activity, create an instance of your CustomAdapter and assign it to your listview.  (this is already in the code example you posted).
5. In your main activity add and remove items from your list of objects as needed.  I typically maintain a separate list of objects, then clear the adapter's list and do an addAll() of my list when data changes, but that's not required.  You could add and remove objects one at a time from the CustomAdapter.

Here's an example of an arrayadapter using textviews for a simple stock quote app.

```
 class StockArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
Context myContext;
ArrayList<Stock> stocks;
int myLayout;
LayoutInflater inflator;

public StockArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    ArrayList<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();
    initialize(context, resource, stocks);
}

public StockArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Stock> stocks) {
    super(context, resource, stocks);

    initialize(context, resource, stocks);

}

private void initialize(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Stock> objects) {
    myContext = context;
    myLayout = resource;
    stocks = objects;
    inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = inflator.inflate(myLayout, parent, false);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById (R.id.nameTextView);
    TextView lastTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lastTextView);
    TextView changeTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.changeTextView);
    nameTextView.setText(stocks.get(position).CompanyName);
    lastTextView.setText(stocks.get(position).LastTrade);
    changeTextView.setText((stocks.get(position).Change));

    return rowView;
   }
}
```